# Echo a property's name, not value?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop

I need to access my dynamic $his->key's name, not its value. See example below:

```
<?php

    class foo {

        public $bar;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->bar = 'I am the value.';
            $this->echobar();
        }

        public function echobar() {
            echo $this->bar;
        }
    }

    $foo = new foo();

?>
```

I basically want to echo **bar**, not *I am the value.* but how?

Comment: `get_object_vars ( object $object )`

Comment: Just do `echo "bar"`.

Comment: I suspect there's more to this question than you're showing, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks @Barmar is right, but still you can do like below:-

```
<?php
    class foo {
        public $bar;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->bar = 'I am the value.';
            $this->echobar();
        }
        public function echobar() {
            echo $this->bar;
        }
    }
    $foo = new foo();
    echo "<pre/>";print_r(array_keys(get_object_vars ($foo))[0]);//get the properties and there values in array key->value pair(through get_object_vars()) format and then get the keys only (properties name) and then print the first one.
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/507775